# Jquery localStorage clipboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm studying jquery with localStorage and want to create somekind of page clipboard tab where you can add product, pictrures etc. to view it later.

This is my jquery code:

```
var count = 0;
jQuery('.add_rem').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    if(jQuery(this).hasClass('remove')) {
      count -= 1;
    }else {
      count += 1;
    }     
    jQuery.each( function(){
      if(jQuery(this).hasClass('remove')){
          if(count == 0) {
            jQuery('.list li.empty').show();
          }
          if($(".remove").attr('id') == localStorage.getItem('id') ) {
              localStorage.removeItem('id');
              $("#"+localStorage.getItem('id')).removeClass('remove');
          }
      } else {
          jQuery('.list li.empty').hide();
          localStorage.setItem('count', count);
          localStorage.setItem('id', jQuery(this).attr('id'));
          if(jQuery(this).attr('id') == localStorage.getItem('id')){
            jQuery(".add_rem#"+localStorage.getItem('id')).addClass("remove"); 
          }
          localStorage.setItem('link', jQuery('.link').attr('href'));
          localStorage.setItem('photo', jQuery('.photo').attr('src'));
          localStorage.setItem('name', jQuery('b.name').text());
        jQuery('#hp-content .wrapper .list').append('<li><a href="'+ localStorage.getItem('link') +'"> <img src="'+ localStorage.getItem('photo') +'" alt="photo" /><br />'+ localStorage.getItem('name') +' </a></li>');
        jQuery('.panel2 a span').text('('+ localStorage.getItem('count') +')');
      }
    jQuery('.panel2 a span').text('('+ localStorage.getItem('count') +')');
 })
})
```

This is the HTML code of one product:

```
<tr>
  <td class="nul">
   <a href="javascript:;" class="add_rem"><img src="/img/check_of.png" alt="Add / remove from clipboard" title="add to clipboard"></a>
  </td>
  <td class="nul">
   <a href="13/test/" class="link">
     <img class="photo" alt="Test" src="images/pl/brak.gif">
   </a>
  </td>
  <td class="nul"><b>Test1 / kk</b></td>
  <td class="nul"><i>Princeton</i></td>
  <td class="nul">College</td>
  <td class="nul">
    <a href="13/test/">
     <img alt="Show" src="images/general/show.gif">
    </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
   </td>
 </tr>
```

This is HTML of clipboard:

```
<div style="" id="clipboard">
  <div class="panels">
    <ul>
      <li class="panel2"><a href="#">Clipboard <span>(0)</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="hp-content"><div id="clipboard-bg">
        <div class="wrapper">
      <ul class="list"> 
       <li class="empty"><strong>Empty.</strong><span class="one">The clipboard is now empty.</span></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

but after page reload all copied elements are erased

### [JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pLPuW/4/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing the initialization of LocalStorage object. I normally use modernizr to do this, that could be something like:

```
if (Modernizr.localstorage) {
    // localStorage starts
    var localStore = window.localStorage;
    localStore.setItem["item_1"] = what_you_want_save_1;
    localStore["item_1"] = what_you_want_save_1;
    localStore.item_1 = what_you_want_save_1;
    // localStorage ends
}
```

And the if you want to get the data from localStorage:

```
if (Modernizr.localstorage) {
    var localStore = window.localStorage;
    if (localStore.item != undefined) {
        item_1 = localStore.item_1;
    }
}
```

I hope this is what you was looking for :)

Comment: If you don't use Modernizr you just have to ignore the two `if`

Comment: and can you tell me how can i select and remember more than one item [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pLPuW/2/)

Comment: You do not need to initialize local storage, it is either part of the windows object or it isn't and as such is a global function. You do not need modernizr to test for it either, if(window.localStorage){}.  Check what is in you localStorage in the chrome dev tools, resources tab. You can watch it there. Do not call localStorage.clear() unless you want to remove everything. Also check your console for any errors thrown by your code.

Comment: @Chris Love - i've got no errors and i have no idea whats wrong

Comment: [Here I have written a easy example how to use local storage](http://jsfiddle.net/newpatriks/39ZzK/). I'm not using modernizr, so it's easy to understand. You can see that the first time you visit doesn't show the value of **item_1**, it's when you refresh that the "Hello" appears. You can play deleting the localstorage variable with the tools that @ChrisLove said, I often use _FireSotrage plus!_ too.

Comment: i can't get it to work i know this is simple but this is my first encounter with localStorage so treat me like an Idiot and explain me how can i store more elements than one cause in my jsfiddle it's not working at all :( [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/pLPuW/2)

Comment: Don't worry. To save more that one element it's the same that save on. Only have to create the element with another `localstore['item_1'] = "value 1"; localstore['item_2'] = "value 2";` etc. And when you receive the data, it's de same: `localStore.item_1` and `localStore.item_2`

Comment: as i understand localStorage is an array?? so can i store the elements in this form `localStorage[name][link][picture][id]` etc?

Comment: Yes. But maybe the best solution is to create a javascript object and save the entire object with all your data. But yes, you're right, localStorage is an key/value array.